# Importing 2 proxies on JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm having problems with my code. I need to import two proxies on my JSP. I don't know why but my code gives an error whenever import my other proxy package. I thought of putting the import codes in an if else statement but it doesn't work. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.String"%>

<%
int i = 1;

if (i == 0){
%>
        <%@ page import ="com.x.x.function" %>
        <%@ page import ="com.x.x.functionViDocument" %>
        <%@ page import ="com.x.x.types.*" %>
<%  
 }else {
%>
        <%@ page import ="com.x.x2.function" %>
        <%@ page import ="com.x.x2.functionViDocument" %>
        <%@ page import ="com.x.x2.types.*" %>
<%  
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do conditional imports in Java. The JSP is converted to a java class (that extends HttpServlet), and your code is not a valid java code.

You can use fully-qualified class names in your code instead. If you need a `Function`, then:

`com.x.x.Function fn1 = ...` and `com.x.x2.Function fn2 = ..`.

However, this is not a good practice. Preferably you should have an interface that both `Function` classes implement, so that you don't have so much conditional copy-pasted code.

Two other things: use capitalized class names (`Function` instead of `function`). And don't write java code in JSPs. Use a servlet instead.